# Print letters from text in my React component like old video games

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get my letters to print to my component at about 500ms each. They should appear side by side as the array completes, but I'm not having any lucky getting that to happen. It just replaces the current letter instead and the time it changes letters is too fast. Here's what I've tried.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


class Printer extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      arr: this.props.text,
      theText: undefined
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.state.arr.forEach( (letter, index) =>
      setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log(letter)
        this.setState( {theText: {[index]: letter}})
      }, 1000)
    )

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p>
          {this.state.theText && Object.values(this.state.theText).map( (letter, index) => <span>{letter}</span>)}
        </p>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }

}

export default Printer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your code here https://codesandbox.io/s/30kv4pn46.

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(letter);
    this.setState(state => ({
      theText: state.theText + letter
    }));
  }, 1000 * index)
```

You had some problems, first if you want to delay the display with setTimeout you should increment the delay by the index. So the first call gets executed in 1s, the second in 2s and so on.

Also you need to update the state functionally, this way you get a snapshot of the last update on state. You have to know that `setState` is asynchronous. Read more here.
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b

Comment: This is great! Thanks so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. (Oh, and thanks for sharing the other bits of knowledge. I have learned more this day!)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can do that with this npm package [react-animated-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-animated-text)

It provides you several animations. If you look at the examples, there is a verticalFadeOut effect, I've checked it and there is a verticalFadeIn. I've edited an example too:

```
export class Wave2 extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { paused: true };
  this.togglePause = this.togglePause.bind(this);
  this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
}

togglePause() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ paused: !prevState.paused }));
}

reset() {
  this.setState('paused', true);
}

render() {
return (
  <div style={exampleStyle}>
    <a onClick={this.togglePause} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
      <Wave
        text="Click Me"
        effect="verticalFadeIn"
        effectChange={2.5}
        effectDirection='down'
        iterations={1}
        paused={this.state.paused}
      />
    </a>
    <br />
    <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={this.togglePause}>Reset</button>

    <div style={codeDivStyle}>
      <pre style={codeStyle}>
        &lt;Wave<br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;text="Click Me"<br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;effect="verticalFadeIn"<br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;effectChange=&#123;2.5}<br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;effectDirection='down'<br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;iterations=&#123;1}<br />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;paused=&#123;this.state.paused}<br />
      />
      </pre>
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a starting point using hooks.

```js
const Typer = ({speed = 100, children}) => {
  const [idx, setidx] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = window.setInterval(() => setidx(v => v + 1), speed);
    return () => window.clearInterval(timer);
  })
  
  return <div>{children.substr(0,idx)}</div>;
};

const App = () => <div>
  <Typer>This is some text to get typed</Typer>
</div>;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```